# Ajax/PHP: Returning values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Q:** I cant find the reason why my code isnt working.

index.php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$Tri_CAPTION=$row['BOOKCAPTION'];
$Tri_IMAGE=$row['BOOKIMAGE'];
$BOOKT=$row['BOOKTITLE'];
$BOOKID=$row['BOOKID'];
$html = $Tri_IMAGE;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)"); # "/images/image.jpg"


echo "<div class=\"mybooks\">
 <a  href=\"".$src."\" data-title=\"$BOOKT\"  data-lightbox=\"example-3\"  alt=\"Home\">
 <img src=\"".$src."\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\"/>  
</a>
 <br />
Title:<strong> 
".$BOOKT."</strong>
<br />

<a onClick=\"forusedata($BOOKID);\" href=\"#\">View Book</a> 

</div>";
  }
?>
```

**Ajax:**

```
<script>    
  function forusedata(newid)
  {         

$.post('insert_home.php',{newid:newid}).done(function(data){
    alert(data);

    });
        $('#Page1').dialog('open');
  }

</script>
```

**insert_home.php**

```
else if(isset($_POST['newid']))
{
$newid = ($_POST['newid']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT BOOKCAPTION FROM book WHERE BOOKID='$newid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['BOOKCAPTION'];
}
 mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Let's start with the basics. What is supposed to happen, and what actually happens? Add any error messages to your question. Check the server error log and add any relevant errors you find there.

Comment: it shoukd output html tags, because html tags is the content of the BOOKCAPTION, What happens is it doesnt output anything

Answer (score 0):

Why does your insert_home.php code start with else if? Is there something missing above it? Since you don't say what is actually not working, I'm going to guess that you're not getting any alert data.

I would change your insert_home.php to:

```
if(isset($_POST['newid'])) {
    $newid = ($_POST['newid']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT BOOKCAPTION FROM book WHERE BOOKID='$newid'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['BOOKCAPTION'];
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
else {
    echo ('no results');
}
```

This will let you know if the problem is in the ajax or in the insert_home.php page.

Comment: i got alot of code at the top, and i laso got the else statement

Comment: the alert(data) doesnt work, as in no output, no alert

Comment: At this point, I suggest you make your entire insert_home.php be:

<?php
echo ('testing the ajax');
?>

If that doesn't give an alert, you know the problem is with the ajax portion. 
If it does give an alert, you know the problem is in your insert_home.php page.